# How to speed up performance of Select Box?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

I a trying to display a long list of countries in a `ion-select`. There are currently 249 countries that i'm trying to load. The rendering, performamce is very slow on my Phone.

```
<ion-list margin-top margin-bottom>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label margin-left style="color:#3498db">Country</ion-label>
      <ion-select margin-right [(ngModel)]="country" okText="Done" placeholder="Select">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of countries" [value]="item.ccode" [selected]="country == item.ccode">{{item.cname}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Is there any way to improve rendering performance?

Comment: From where are you getting `249` records?

Comment: @Sampath From my server

Comment: If below solution is working then no issues.But you can go for a caching solution too.i.e. you can store those countries on your device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it would be by using a `Modal`. You could also add a searchbar on top, so the users could find the target country easily. The following is just a simplified demo (please let me know if you find any errors, since I've removed a lot of not-related code from it).

**Please also notice that instead of using an `ion-list` and one `ion-item` for each country, I'm using regular `div` in the view.** That's because the list of countries is kind of big (~250), and using `ion-list` and `ion-item` that are components from Ionic (based on Angular) will require to initialize these components, to render them, and then to create/destroy them every time you filter the countries. **In the demo, since they're just html elements (with a few simple style rules), the performance is great even in very old mobile devices.**

**Controller**

```
// Angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({ 
    selector: 'page-country-list', 
    templateUrl: 'country-list.html' 
    })
export class CountryListPage {

    public countries: Array<any>;
    public countriesToShow: Array<any>;

    constructor(private paramsCtrl: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        // Get the data as a parameter
        this.countries = paramsCtrl.get('countries');

        // Initialize the list of countries to show in the view
        this.initializeCountriesToShow();
    }

    public initializeCountriesToShow(): void {
        // Clone the list of countries so we don't modify the original copy
        this.countriesToShow = [...this.countries];
    }

    public filterCountries(ev: any): void {
        // Reset countries back to all of the countries
        this.initializeCountriesToShow();

        // Set val to the value of the searchbar
        let val = ev.target.value;

        // If the value is an empty string don't filter the countries
        if (val && val.trim() != '') {
            this.countriesToShow = this.countriesToShow.filter((country) => {
                return (country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
        }
    }

    // Method that returns the selected country to the caller
    public selectCountry(country: any): void {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss(country);
    }

    // Method that closes the modal without returning anything
    public close(): void {
        this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Countries</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons right>
            <button (click)="close()" ion-button icon-only>
                <ion-icon color="light" class="close-icon" name="close"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-searchbar placeholder="Type the name here..." (ionInput)="filterCountries($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="country-list">
        <div tappable (click)="selectCountry(country)" class="country-item" *ngFor="let country of countriesToShow">
            {{ country.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Styles**

```
.ios, .md {
    page-country-list {

        div.country-item {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 16px;
            margin-left: 16px;
            margin-top: 16px;
            padding-bottom: 16px;
            border-bottom: 0.55px solid map-get($colors, light);

            &:last-child {
                border-bottom: none;
            }
        }

        ion-navbar {
            .close-icon {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
                padding-right: 8px;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Caller component**

Then, in order to show the modal, you can do something like this:

```
constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {}

// ...

public showCountryDropdown(): void {

    // Create the modal
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('CountryListPage');

    // Handle the result
    modal.onDidDismiss(country => {
        if (country) {
            // Handle the selected country
            // ...
        }
    });

    // Show the modal
    modal.present();
}
```

**Note**: In the demo, I'm assuming that each `country` item has a property `name`.